# Get entity by id

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using gorilla mux for my routes and I pass an id.

Using that Id how can I get a entity from datastore.

```
param := mux.Vars(r)
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
item := []Item{}
pr, err := datastore.NewQuery("Item").Filter("ID = ", param["id"]).GetAll(c, &item)
```

And here I'm stuck, I tried using filter but it doesn't work.

What do I have to do next?

Comment: You may be getting confused with prior experience with a data modeling language like SQL.  A _datastore key_ is not the same thing as an SQL _primary key column_, in the sense that a datastore key is an entirely **separate thing** from the _properties_ of an entity.  Queries should only talk about entity properties.  In contrast, an SQL primary key column is still a column.  If you have a datastore key, use the `datastore.Get` or `datastore.GetMulti` functions.  No querying needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if you are using integer or string ids for entities. I'll assume integer because it requires a little more code. First, create a key:

```
 n, err := strconv.ParseInt(param["id"], 10, 64)
 if err != nil {
    // handle error
 }
 key := datastore.NewKey(c, "Item", "", n, nil)
```

Now that you have key, you can fetch the entity:

```
 var item Item
 if err := datastore.Get(c, key, &item); err != nil {
     // handle error
 }
```

It's more efficient to [get](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#Get) the entity than to query for the entity. If you do want to query by id, then see [key filters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/queries#Go_Key_filters) in the App Engine docs.

Comment: `key := datastore.NewKey(c, "Item", "", n, defaultItemList(c))` I used this but I get datastore: `invalid entity type`

Comment: What's the value of the pointer you're passing to `datastore.Get`?  You have not produced enough source code to let others confirm that you're not making the mistake mentioned in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/TfL11t8YX-4.  ErrInvalidEntityType is documented in https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference so your code must be passing in some unexpected destination value in `datastore.Get`.

Comment: For example, if you've done `item := []Item{}`, and you're trying to call `datastore.Get(c, key, item)`, that will certainly fail: `item` is not a struct pointer.  You need to do `item := Item{}` and then `datastore.Get(c, key, &item)` should do something effective.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an id, you don't need to use a query. A faster and cheaper way is to create a key and retrieve this entity directly from the Datastore.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/entities#Go_Retrieving_an_entity